# How to prevent the keyboard on Android browsers from changing the height of the page?

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

When clicking on an an `input` type=text, a keyboard comes up.  Unfortunately, that changes the height of the web page, so that all the thinks that were "stickied" to the bottom of the page want to come up above the keyboard.

And, in my case, the element that's anchored to the bottom of the page (e.g. the Apply button below) ends up covering the next input element (e.g. Max textbox), so that when the user presses `Next` on the virtual keyboard, you can't see it at all because the button is still covering it.

My question is whether there is any way to prevent the keyboard from changing the height of the page?

P.S.  On iOS it works like you would expect.  Bringing up the keyboard doesn't change the dimensions of the page.

[image]

Comment: perhaps detect if an input has focus and hide the "footer" - off the top of my head

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is default behavior on Android devices. As I know, you can not prevent this.